# find and replace a string with quotes and brackets in clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

I am trying to replace:

`sum("PUBLIC"."ORDERS"."TOTAL") AS "sum"`

In the string:

`SELECT "PUBLIC"."ORDERS"."TAX" AS "TAX", sum("PUBLIC"."ORDERS"."TOTAL") AS "sum" FROM "PUBLIC"."ORDERS" GROUP BY "PUBLIC"."ORDERS"."TAX" ORDER BY "PUBLIC"."ORDERS"."TAX" ASC`

The issue is presence of quotes `"`, parentheses `(` `)` and dots `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes just need to have a backslash in front of them:

```
user=> (def s "SELECT \"PUBLIC\".\"ORDERS\".\"TAX\" AS \"TAX\", sum(\"PUBLIC\".\"ORDERS\".\"TOTAL\") AS \"sum\" FROM \"PUBLIC\".\"ORDERS\" GROUP BY \"PUBLIC\".\"ORDERS\".\"TAX\" ORDER BY \"PUBLIC\".\"ORDERS\".\"TAX\" ASC")

#'user/s

user=> (.replace s "sum(\"PUBLIC\".\"ORDERS\".\"TOTAL\") AS \"sum\"" "new string")

"SELECT \"PUBLIC\".\"ORDERS\".\"TAX\" AS \"TAX\", new string FROM \"PUBLIC\".\"ORDERS\" GROUP BY \"PUBLIC\".\"ORDERS\".\"TAX\" ORDER BY \"PUBLIC\".\"ORDERS\".\"TAX\" ASC"
```

Comment: Can't edit the original string, the one you have in variable `s`. Unless there a way to add backslashes dynamically?

Comment: The backslashes are just an encoding detail. In what form is the original string?

Comment: Plain string: `SELECT "PUBLIC"."ORDERS"."TAX" AS "TAX", sum("PUBLIC"."ORDERS"."TOTAL") AS "sum" FROM "PUBLIC"."ORDERS" GROUP BY "PUBLIC"."ORDERS"."TAX" ORDER BY "PUBLIC"."ORDERS"."TAX" ASC`

Comment: In what medium does it exist? Text file? Java string?

Comment: Then it is identical to the s variable in the answer. The backslashes don't really exist in the in-memory form of the string. Neither do the outer quotes, of course. The backslashes and outer quotes are just conventions used to enable a parser to distinguish whats part of a string object and what isnt.